# PHP open_basedir

Tags: php, apache, open-basedir

I'm getting the following PHP warning:

```
PHP Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/pear//home/domain.nl/application/views/helpers/HeadLink.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/usr/share/php:/home/domain.nl/:/usr/share/pear:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/tmp:/etc/phpmyadmin:/usr/lib/php4:/usr/lib/php5:/opt/ioncube/lib) in /home/domain.nl/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 186
```

How come `/usr/share/pear//home/domain.nl/application/views/helpers/..` is not within the allowed path `/usr/share/pear`?

Thanks,

Martijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37476

Says is_readable throws this warning for not existing files if php is older than 5.2.

And your path looks like a not existing one. I mean probably it should start with /home/
domain.nl, and the /usr/share/pear/ part is unintentional. (Perhaps the include_path directive prepended?)

Comment: The server's running 5.3.10, so I guess the issue still exists. The include_path is indeed being prepended (default behavior of Zend Framework's Loader).